# jQuery selector for responsive bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I'm using bootstrap to have responsive UI. When page is normally viewed i have table with a button. When i press button i need to select closest tr with role="row". I managed to do that using this:

```
var selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr[role="row"]');
```

When page goes to responsive mode my table gets additional tr element. How can i select first parent that is tr with role="row" so that selector works in both cases.

Normal page:

```
        <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
            <td tabindex="0"></td>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">Event1</td>
            <td>Something1</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>
                <button class="editDetail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
            <td tabindex="1"></td>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">Event2</td>
            <td>Something2</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>
                <button class="editDetail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Responsive page

```
        <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
            <td tabindex="0"></td>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">Event1</td>
            <td>Something1</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="child">
            <td class="child" colspan="6">
            <ul data-dtr-index="0">
                <li data-dtr-index="4">
                    <span class="dtr-data">YES</span>
                </li>
                <li data-dtr-index="5">
                    <span class="dtr-title"></span> 
                    <span class="dtr-data">
                    <button class="editDetail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
            <td tabindex="0"></td>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">Event2</td>
            <td>Something2</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="child">
            <td class="child" colspan="6">
            <ul data-dtr-index="0">
                <li data-dtr-index="4">
                    <span class="dtr-data">YES</span>
                </li>
                <li data-dtr-index="5">
                    <span class="dtr-title"></span> 
                    <span class="dtr-data">
                    <button class="editDetail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Do you want to get data from nearest/closest tr which has role "row" or you want to get the data from the current tr where button click event is triggered?

Comment: I need data from closest tr (second previous element in responsive case) that has role "row"

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, try replacing this:

```
var selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr[role="row"]');
```

by this:

```
var selectedRow = $(this).parents('tr[role="row"]');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, unfortunately i'm getting error while in responsive mode. Notice how there are two buttons, one is hidden and another one is displayed in new <tr> element. That's the level i'm starting with on click and for some reason i can't select top tr element with targeted tag. EDIT: just realized now that i don't need parent but previous tr element with role="row"

Comment: Can you please provide the scenario in a JSFIddle? It would be much easier to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you can use below code to get the required tr with role "row"

```
var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
var roleAttr = parentRow.attr('role');
if (typeof roleAttr !== typeof undefined && roleAttr !== false) {
if(roleAttr == "row")
{
//Write your code here
}
}
else {
var roleRow = parentRow.prev('tr[role="row"]'); //tr with role 'row'
}
```

There is one more simple approach, if you don't want to go with this code.
you can use window.width to get the current resolution of your screen and based on the current resolution you can write your code accordingly.

Hope this will help you.